# Capacitors selections for proper bandwidh

Tags: amplifier, decoupling-capacitor, pspice, orcad, bypass-capacitor

I need to design an amplifier in orcad with

Vin  = 10mVac

Vout = 2,5Vac

RLoad = 50 ohm

The low frequency fLow = 50Hz

fHigh = 20kHz

I came up with this schematic
[image: schematic]

I need to select the right value for the capacitors in order to get the right amoplification and cutoff frequencies.

Here I have the time simulation
[image: time simulation]

And the frequency simulation

[image: time simulation]

Can you help me?

Comment: How precise to you have to be.  For example, do you have to have -3db exactly at 20Hz or can it be lower than 20Hz.  The flat part of the curve between 20 and 20kHz is going to have a gain that is not impacted much by the capacitors.  Can you change other things to ge the gain you want?  I can't read your plots so I'm not sure where you are starting from.

Comment: C2 is way too low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you help me?

You are not going to get reasonably low distortion with a gain of 250 with your front-end transistor circuit. Try splitting the gain into two sections and cascade them so that each has a gain of about 16. Don't use emitter resistor bypass capacitors to get high gain - you get crappy distortion and noisy outputs.

In fact, I don't know what you are not considering an op-amp to give you the gain stage; An OPA209 op-amp would work rather nicely as the gain stage.

Of course, what I would find objectionable in terms of distortion may be perfectly fine for someone else.